# Python: find string in string

Tags: python-2.7

I want to print out the IDs that are in between ">sp|" and "|" from a file, so the output should be:

```
Q12955
Q16659
Q7Z7A1
```

Example file f:

```
>sp|Q12955|ANK3_HUMAN Ankyrin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ANK3 PE=1 SV=3
MAHAASQLKKNRDLEINAEEEPEKKRKHRKRSRDRKKKSDANASYLRAARAGHLEKALDY
IKNGVDINICNQNGLNALHLASKEGHVEVVSELLQREANVDAATKKGNTALHIASLAGQA

>sp|Q16659|MK06_HUMAN Mitogen-activated protein kinase 6 OS=Homo sapiens GN=MAPK6 PE=1 SV=1

MAEKFESLMNIHGFDLGSRYMDLKPLGCGGNGLVFSAVDNDCDKRVAIKKIVLTDPQSVK
HALREIKIIRRLDHDNIVKVFEILGPSGSQLTDDVGSLTELNSVYIVQEYMETDLANVLE
QGPLLEEHARLFMYQLLRGLKYIHSANVLHRDLKPANLFINTEDLVLKIGDFGLARIMDP

>sp|Q7Z7A1|CNTRL_HUMAN Centriolin OS=Homo sapiens GN=CNTRL PE=1 SV=2

MKKGSQQKIFSKAKIPSSSHSPIPSSMSNMRSRSLSPLIGSETLPFHSGGQWCEQVEIAD
ENNMLLDYQDHKGADSHAGVRYITEALIKKLTKQDNLALIKSLNLSLSKDGGKKFKYIEN
LEKCVKLEVLNLSYNLIGKIEKLDKLLKLRELNLSYNKISKIEGIENMCNLQKLNLAGNE
```

My code:

```
f=open('seq.fasta','r')

for idline in f:
    ID = re.findall('|......|',idline)
    print ID
    break
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is always in the middle of the two vertical bars then you could do something like this and not even worry about regular expressions. (Judging by your example it is safe to assume they are always in the middle!)

```
f=open('seq.fasta','r')

for idline in f:
    if '>' in idline:
        lineSplit = idline.split('|')
        ID = lineSplit[1]
        print ID
```

#### Output

```
Q12955
Q16659
Q7Z7A1
```

If it does vary you could do something like this and loop through until you get the section beginning with Q and then print that. The two give you the same results.

```
f=open('seq.fasta','r')

for idline in f:
    if '>' in idline:
        lineSplit = idline.split('|')
        for section in lineSplit:
            if (('OS=' not in section) and ('>sp' not in section)):
                ID = section
                print ID
```

Comment: This only works if `ID` is at the beginning of the line. Depending on the FASTA file, it could be anywhere in the line beginning with `>`.